# Substituting Dried Shiitake Mushrooms for Fresh

Tags: substitutions, mushrooms

I have a recipe that calls for 12 oz of fresh Shiitake mushrooms.  Due to cost and availability concerns, I decided to get dried instead, figuring I would be able to find information about how to substitute dried Shiitake mushrooms for fresh, but I have been unable.

What would an appropriate ratio be for substituting dried shiitakes for fresh?

Answer (score 5):

I answered a question like this previously. [How to work with Dried Mushrooms?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/how-to-work-with-dried-mushrooms/8662#8662)

Cold water - the best way to keep the original flavour.

It will take at least couple of hours.

1. I would soak them in cold water for about 15 mins
2. Pour all the water out. Put in fresh water and keep soaking it. I will do this step couple of times. Remember you may retain the water as flavour, but you have to clean the mushroom and make sure the bitterness is gone. Also, I must say the imported Chinese mushroom must be handled carefully as there have been reports their process may contain some chemicals.
3. After a couple of hours, make sure the mushrooms are soft and take them out of water and drive them thoroughly. You may keep the water if you wish. The mushrooms are good for steamed and stir-fry.

Hot water

If you are in rush, then you may use hot or warm water. You still have to go through the cleaning process, but the time required will be less.

Answer (score 3):

Most of a fresh mushroom consists of water.

One retail website claims that it takes a whole pound fresh to make 3 ounces of dried shiitakes; a nutritional website claims that about 83g of a 100g serving is water.

As for reconstituting them, I found these instructions:
 - steep them in warm water broth for ~ 30 min 
OR 
 - add them to a simmering liquid for 10-15 min

See this related question:
[How to work with Dried Mushrooms?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/how-to-work-with-dried-mushrooms)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do with dried mushrooms is reconstitute them before use. Place them in a small bowl and just about cover them with boiling water. Let sit for 20 mintues or so. They should resume their original volume and cook with them as if they were fresh. The remaining liquid will be strongly flavored so try to include that in your recipe if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found that 20g of dried shitake rehydrated to 125g so if you divide your fresh quantity by 6 you should be about right.