# Approximating dried mushroom texture without

Tags: substitutions, mushrooms, dehydrating

For [yet](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28577/15) [another](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/15935/15) variation on using dried/fresh mushrooms, I would like to know how to approximate the texture of dried mushrooms using fresh.

My intent is to make a leek-miso soup and I would like to add dried shiitake for their texture (flavor too, sure, but it is already a flavorful soup). Unfortunately, the market near me only has fresh mushrooms (portabella, baby bella, snow cap, and other normals). But alas, I also do not have a food dehydrator.

How can I manipulate the mushrooms to approximate the same chewy texture? My thought is that long, slow baking at a very low temp would dry them out. Is this intuition right? Should I prep the mushrooms before hand in anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have accidentally gotten that texture by putting leftover stir-fried sliced shitake in the fridge uncovered. Leather.

Comment: So essentially stir fry in oil, dehydrate in fridge; were the shiitake mushrooms fresh to begin with?

Comment: yes indeed. lived in Beijing so fresh was plentiful. fried in minimal oil -not dripping- but plenty of salty seasoning. that probably drew out water. some fridges more drying than others (never saw condensation in mine)

Comment: I think I will give this one a shot next time I run into the issue, thanks